# Integrate an ASP.NET Razor Web Site (e.g. MiniBlog) as a module of an ASP.NET MVC Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, integration

[MiniBlog](https://github.com/madskristensen/miniblog) is awesome. I want to incorporate it into my existing Web Application.

The **existing ASP.NET MVC Web Application**

- is hosted in a Windows Azure Website,
- has its application structure in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/bigfont/BigFont/tree/master/BigFont.MVC), and
- is live at [bigfont.ca](https://www.bigfont.ca).

My fork of [MiniBlog](https://github.com/madskristensen/miniblog) is an **ASP.NET Razor Web Site** and

- is currently hosted in another Windows Azure Website and
- is live at [mini-blog.azurewebsites.net](http://mini-blog.azurewebsites.net/)

I would like to **integrate the Web Site into the Web Application** so that:

1. the url for the blog is bigfont.ca/blog,
2. blog content sits in the existing web app content area (see image below),
3. the web application and MiniBlog web site have clear separation,
4. it basically looks like this:

[image: Blog Integrated into Web Application]

My implementation ideas include:

1. use an iFrame to include the MiniBlog in the existing web app
2. create an MVC.NET view that represents the blog
3. put the MiniBlog into its own [MVC Area](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx)

Basically, I would like to keep the MiniBlog as an independent and interchangeable component of the Web Application.

For instance, the [Orchard CMS](http://www.orchardproject.net/) does this by making ASP.NET Projects into separate modules.

What strategy, if any, exists for making an ASP.NET Web Site a module within an ASP.NET Web Application?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an ASP.NET MVC Area. I used this general approach.

1. Create a new MVC.NET area called MiniBlog.
2. Copy-and-paste the necessary MiniBlog components one at a time into the new Area.
3. Edit the Web.config as necessary.
4. Repeat step 2 and 3 until complete.

It was quite tricky. The final solution lacked a clear separation between MiniBlog and the rest of the MVC.NET website. I wasn't satisfied with the solution. It might be that ASP.NET Web Pages and ASP.NET MVC aren't meant to work together in this way.

Comment: Care to run us through the process? Any gotchas or was it plain sailing?